# Error en la funcion

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hola estoy teniendo problemas con esta funcion para calcular la antiguedad, ya que hay momentos que me da bien la antiguedad y en otras ocaciones no y la verdad no se a que se puede deber, por ejemplo si la fecha de ingreso es igual a '2022-07-01 00:00:00.000' y calculo la antiguedad hasta la fecha me devuelve 10 meses y 26 dias cuando claramente son 11 meses y 26 dias

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad]
    (
        @fecha DATETIME
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN (
        SELECT  Id_Usu,
               CASE
                  WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
                  ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha) -
                       CASE
                          WHEN MONTH(fechaingreso) > MONTH(@fecha) OR
                               (MONTH(fechaingreso) = MONTH(@fecha) AND DAY(fechaingreso) > DAY(@fecha)) THEN 1
                          ELSE 0
                       END
               END AS años,
               CASE
                  WHEN MONTH(fechaingreso) > MONTH(@fecha) OR
                       (MONTH(fechaingreso) = MONTH(@fecha) AND DAY(fechaingreso) > DAY(@fecha)) THEN
                       12 - MONTH(fechaingreso) + MONTH(@fecha) - 1
                  ELSE
                       MONTH(@fecha) - MONTH(fechaingreso)
               END AS meses,
               CASE
                  WHEN DAY(fechaingreso) > DAY(@fecha) THEN
                       DAY(EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso))) - DAY(fechaingreso) + DAY(@fecha)
                  ELSE
                       DAY(@fecha) - DAY(fechaingreso)
               END AS dias
        FROM Empleados
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes unos cuantos problemas en los cálculos. El más problemático me resultó ser los días porque tuve que cambiar la lógica para acercar la fecha actual a la fecha de ingreso y no al revés porque alteraba la cantidad de días cuando había meses cortos.

```
    ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionCalcularAntiguedad]
    (
        @fecha DATETIME
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
    RETURN
    WITH cteMeses AS(
        SELECT  Id_Usu,
               fechaingreso,
               CASE
                  WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
                  WHEN DATEADD( YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso) >= @fecha
                    THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha) - 1
                    ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha)
               END AS años,
               CASE
                  WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
                  WHEN DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso) > @fecha
                    THEN (DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha) - 1) % 12
                    ELSE DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha) % 12
               END AS meses
        FROM Empleados
    )
    SELECT Id_Usu,
           años,
           meses,
           CASE
              WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
              ELSE DATEDIFF( DAY, fechaingreso, DATEADD( MONTH, -meses, DATEADD( YEAR, -años, @fecha))) END AS dias
    FROM cteMeses;
```

Dejo también la prueba que hice.

```
CREATE TABLE #Empleados(
    Id_Usu  int,
    fechaingreso    date
);

WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
INSERT INTO #Empleados
SELECT n, DATEADD( DD, -n, GETDATE())
FROM cteTally;
     

DECLARE @fecha DATETIME = GETDATE();
    
WITH cteMeses AS(
    SELECT  Id_Usu,
            fechaingreso,
            CASE
                WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
                WHEN DATEADD( YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso) >= @fecha
                THEN DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha) - 1
                ELSE DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha)
            END AS años,
            CASE
                WHEN @fecha < fechaingreso THEN 0
                WHEN DATEADD( MONTH, DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso) > @fecha
                THEN (DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha) - 1) % 12
                ELSE DATEDIFF( MONTH, fechaingreso, @fecha) % 12
            END AS meses
    FROM #Empleados
)
SELECT Id_Usu,
        DATEADD( YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, fechaingreso, @fecha), fechaingreso),
        años,
        meses,
        DATEDIFF( DAY, fechaingreso, DATEADD( MONTH, -meses, DATEADD( YEAR, -años, @fecha))) dias
FROM cteMeses;

GO

DROP TABLE #Empleados;
```

Comment: Veo dos detalles: Retornas una fecha en el conjunto de datos, en una columna sin nombre, que parece ser la fecha del último aniversario, pero que no era parte del conjunto original o de la descripción del problema. Y en el cálculo de los días no tomas en cuenta si la fecha del cálculo es anterior a la fecha de ingreso, en cuyo caso habría que retornar 0, como si se hace con los años y meses.

Comment: Tienes razón, en la primera parte, esa fecha era parte de las pruebas y olvidé borrarla. En la otra parte olvidé incluirlo y ciertamente puede generar resultados absurdos con años y meses en ceros y días negativos. Los voy a corregir.

Comment: Comos siempre, muy buena respuesta @Luis. Un saludo.